# How to set default enum value if we insert a invalid enum value in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, enums

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `enum_test` ( 
`id` int(10) default NULL, 
`value` enum('YES','NO') NOT NULL default 'YES' 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

then execute below query

```
INSERT INTO enum_test(id) VALUES (2);  set 'YES' in `enum` field.
INSERT INTO enum_test(id,value) VALUES (2,1);  set 'YES' in `enum` field.
```

---

But

```
 //why below query set blank value in enum field??  
  INSERT INTO enum_test(id, value) VALUES (2, 'YESS');
```

I want that if a user insert a value that does not exist in `enum`  field then it shoud set the default value of `enum`
how to do that?

Comment: Why would you silently want to ignore possible bugs in the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Tomas' answer for a trigger or maybe use a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.html).

You basically are getting ***a*** default value inserted. In strict mode an error will be thrown. Otherwise:

[`http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

> If you insert an invalid value into an
>   ENUM (that is, a string not present in
>   the list of permitted values), the
>   empty string is inserted instead as a
>   special error value. This string can
>   be distinguished from a “normal” empty
>   string by the fact that this string
>   has the numeric value 0. More about
>   this later.

Answer (score 6):

Use a trigger function, like this:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON enum_test
-> FOR EACH ROW
-> BEGIN
->     IF (NEW.value != 'YES' AND NEW.value != 'NO')
->         SET NEW.value = '';
->     END IF;
-> END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

More on triggers here: [Mysql manual, trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

**edit:**
As suggested, it's also possible to define stored procedure and call if from the trigger, which I'd consider better for database maintainability. 
Triggers are part of database definition, so you add this to any sql file with CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: how to use trigger in php mysql?? where do i write this query? on `my database connection page` so that only executed once or need to write on the page where i insert data??

Comment: You define triggers inside your Database, i.e. connect using mysql cli client and execute sql commands. Alternatively, you would use a gui client, like MySQL Workbench. The solution is independent on PHP itself.